# semantic ui modal print using printjs not getting result

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, printjs

semantic ui modal ptint using printjs library. but the result is not 
correctly showing the expected modal print.
help ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#logIn').click(function(){
$('#modaldiv').modal('show');    
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="modaldiv" class="ui modal">

<button type="ui button" id="button" onclick="printJS({ printable: 
     'modaldiv',type: 'html',showModal:true, printContainer: 
      true,copyTagClasses: true})">
       Print
</button>  //print button and printjs command active
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">
Profile Picture
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="ui medium image">
<img src="img/bmw5.png">
</div>
<div class="description">
<div class="ui header">We've auto-chosen a profile image for you.</div>
<p>We've grabbed the following image from the <a href="#" 
target="_blank">gravatar</a> image associated with your registered e-mail address.</p>
<p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<div class="ui black button">
Nope
</div>
<div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
Yep, that's me
<i class="checkmark icon"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<a class="item ui button" id="logIn">
<i class="user icon"></i> Log In 
</a>  // modal open login button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue printing this modal is not related to print.js. The modal has a negative `margin-top` applied style which is the cause of issue when printing it.

In this fiddle, you can test using the `Print2` button, it will print another html element content inside the same modal, without any issues.

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/y8e4ga8p/

Comment: thanks for the solution. i got the result. thanks a lot.